# MagicalRecord create entity nil

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm new to using CoreData and MagicalRecord. I have this in my `AppDelegate` and not sure why there's an issue.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStack];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
    NSEntityDescription *desc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"GFSetModel" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    GFSetModel *test = [GFSetModel MR_createEntityInContext:context];
    return YES;
}
```

`desc` is always nil for some reason and since `MR_createEntityInContext` calls `entityForName: inManagedObjectContext:context`, it makes the test object nil as well. I tried different default contexts. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I didn't make a `.xcdatamodeld` and that was the reason.